# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server timeout

Tags: selenium-webdriver, specflow

I'm getting the following error from my TeamCity CI server. The Specflow BDD I'm running works fine locally - the build server has its firewall turned off, All ports open, IE, Firefox and Chrome drivers installed - same result with all 3 drivers. I've set timeouts to 100 seconds, tried putting the thread to sleep without change. Is there a way to run the test manually on the CI server to see what the issue is?

Test(s) failed. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http:// localhost:49227 /session/1647d43b-06dd-4c41-b0b3-2de687f0b7e1/element timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)

Comment: Hi Mike did you fix this problem?

Comment: The issue was related to an incorrect path I was passing in through TeamCity - the build server could not find the driver executable